# How does Angular know which elements are known and which are not?

Tags: angular, typescript

`<foo>`- it is a randomly named tag, not registered anywhere and it makes sense that it appears as invalid
`<p>` is valid because it is a native HTML element - does Angular have a list of native elements? What is the knowledge source for the validity of this element?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Not only HTML but also HTML5 tags are all listed. Other unknown tags will be considered as component tag, but also you can skip this checking by adding CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA to ngModule decorator as `schemas` field.

Comment: okay, thanks, but where is the list of valid tags? where is the source of knowledge of them?

Comment: The angular language service is responsible for building a tree of all the components and which are included in the models and thus it shows this error based on this tree.

Comment: @misa130 do you mean this https://angular.io/guide/language-service ?

Comment: I have updated the question by one more screenshot. Could you please take a look at the second picture? Do you know if the source of the knowledge about native elements in both cases the same?